# deleting flowFiles in queues programatically by REST API

Tags: rest, apache-nifi

**i want to clear  'response' queue  and  any other  queues  if processor is  stopped because of failure( i stop  it  with  'template' which  works similar to rest api) .** 
I  have read  this:https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html
but i  have no idea  how can i use  it  to fullfile my idea.

1. I mean  it  would  be perfect  if i can  clear  response queue ,in case, i
   have at least  1 flowfile in failure queue. is it possible?
2. Can i   use Put  request  for  deleting  queues i mean is there any ,state  for  flowfiles in  queues to set it as an empty or deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your browser's Developer Tools window, use the UI to clear a queue while monitoring the network tab. Everything the Apache NiFi UI does is performed via the REST API. You will be able to see exactly what requests are sent to the server to clear the connection queue and can recreate that programmatically.

The specific API endpoint you want in this case is `POST /flowfile-queues/{id}/drop-requests` where `{id}` is the connection ID.